# PHP DateTime Interval errors

Tags: php, datetime, intervals, dateinterval

```
if (empty($krow['BUSSTRT'])){ 
    $busts = $ts->add(new DateInterval('PT6i5s'));
    $busDate = $busts->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
    echo "busDate:".$busDate."<br>\n";
}else{
    $busts = new DateTime($krow['BUSSTRT']);
    $busDate = $busts->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
    echo "busSTRT:".$busDate."<br>\n";
}   

if (empty($krow['LAMISTRT'])){ 
    echo "lamistrt is empty::::";
    $lamts = $busts->add(new DateInterval('PT11is'));
    $lamDate = $lamts->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
    echo "lamDate:".$lamDate."<br>\n";
}else{
    $lamts = new DateTime($krow['LAMISTRT']);
    $lamDate = $lamts->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
    echo "lamistrt:".$lamDate."<br>\n";
}
```

The code above is throwing the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (PT11i3s)'

when `$bustDate` is:

busSTRT:02/06/2015 03:53:56
lamistrt is empty::::

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `DateInterval()` to create an interval you use `M` for minutes, not `i`. Also, if there are no seconds you must omit it from the interval declaration:

```
$busts = $ts->add(new DateInterval('PT6M5S'));
$lamts = $busts->add(new DateInterval('PT11M'));
```

`i` is used for getting the number of minutes in a date interval:

```
echo $intervalObj->i; // get minutes
```

Comment: Thank you John.  I was thrown off by this http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: And since that DateInterval terminology is ... interesting, have a look at something like Carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/ - that uses real english for things and extends DateTime